# Trying to solve an equation of a squared floor value.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I was given the following exercise:

$\lfloor x-\frac{1}{2} \rfloor^2 = 25$

**I am not sure if my way is correct.** **I will try to show it as quick as I can.**

---

First, simplifying the term:

$ \lfloor x-\frac{1}{2} \rfloor^2 $ = $\lfloor \left(\:x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\rfloor$ =
$ \lfloor \left(\:x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot \left(\:x-\frac{1}{2}\right)\rfloor $ = $\lfloor x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}\rfloor$

Using the properties of the floor value:

1. $\hspace{0.10cm} \lfloor x\rfloor \le x<\lfloor \:x\rfloor \:+1$
2. $\hspace{0.25cm} x-1<\lfloor \:x\rfloor \:\le \:x$

I can turn **the simplified term**, that I know is **equal to 25** to the following inequality:

---

$ \lfloor x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}\rfloor \leq x^2-x+\frac{1}{4} < \lfloor x^2-x+\frac{1}{4}\rfloor + 1$

using the fact it is equal to 25, we get:

$ 25 \leq x^2-x+\frac{1}{4} < 26 $

we can subtract both sides by a $\frac{1}{4}$:

$ 24\frac{3}{4} \leq x^2-x < 25\frac{3}{4} $

---

so, now I have to solve the two inequalities, the left one, and the right one in order to get the intersection of the $x$ values which should be, the final answer.

**The left inequality:**

$ 24\frac{3}{4} \leq x^2-x $

Moving sides:

$ 0 \leq x^2 - x - 24\frac{3}{4} $

so we can solve the quadratic equation $ x^2 - x - 24\frac{3}{4} = 0 $ , and use a parabola scheme to see where the expression was greater or equal to 0 (non-negative):

**If I know how to insert a graph here - This is where I would do that.**
Because x^2 has a positive multiplier before him (the **a=1**, I don't know how to say it in english), it is a "smiling parabola" that goes through the x-axis in the dots $\left(\frac{1+10}{2},\:0\right)$, $\left(\frac{1-10}{2},\:0\right)$

so the expression would be non-negative when $x\geq \frac{1+10}{2} =5.5$

---

**The right inequality:**

$x^2-x < 25\frac{3}{4} $

Moving sides:

$ x^2-x-25\frac{3}{4} < 0 $

so we can solve the quadratic equation $ x^2-x-25\frac{3}{4} = 0 $ , and use a parabola scheme to see where the expression was less than 0 (negative):

**If I know how to insert a graph here - This is where I would do that.**
Because x^2 has a positive multiplier before him (the **a=1**, I don't know how to say it in english), it is a "smiling parabola" that goes through the x-axis in the dots $ (\frac{1-\sqrt{104}}{2}, 0)$ and $(\frac{1+\sqrt{104}}{2}, 0)$.

so the expression would be negative when $\frac{1-\sqrt{104}}{2}<x<\frac{1+\sqrt{104}}{2} $

$\sqrt{104} > \sqrt{100} = 10 \rightarrow  \sqrt{104} > 10$

$ 1+\sqrt{104} > 11 \rightarrow \frac{1+\sqrt{104}}{2}>\frac{11}{2}=5.5$

---

so, because I found that $\frac{1+\sqrt{104}}{2}>5.5$,

$x\geq5.5$ (from the left inequality)

and $\frac{1-\sqrt{104}}{2}<x<\frac{1+\sqrt{104}}{2} $ (from the right inequality)

**So, can I say** that the intersection of those $x$ values is

$5.5\le x\:<\:\frac{1+\sqrt{104}}{2}$

and that means that **that this is the final solution for the exercise**?
Is it correct?

Thank you for reading. I would more than like to hear what I have done wrong, if there's something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used $\lfloor x\rfloor ^2=\lfloor x^2\rfloor$ in your first line which is not true in general.(Quick reason without conterexample: The left hand side is discontinuos at $x$ iff $x\in\mathbb Z$ while the rhs is discontinuos at $x$ iff $x^2\in\mathbb Z$)

Also, your final answer only shows positive solutions. However if there are positive ones there should definitely be negative ones too. That how you could quickly see that something must be off.

---

Why not just
$$
\lfloor x - \frac{1}{2}\rfloor^2=25\\
\iff \lfloor x - \frac{1}{2}\rfloor \in \{-5,5\}\\
\iff (x-\frac{1}{2})\in[5,6)\cup[-5,-4) \\
\iff x\in [5.5,6.5)\cup[-4.5,-3.5)\\
$$

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are making this *far* harder than in needs to be.

\begin{align*}
\left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor^2 = 25
&\iff \left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = 5 \quad\text{or}\quad \left\lfloor x-\frac{1}{2} \right\rfloor = -5.
\end{align*}

By definition of $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$, this reduces to
\begin{align*}
&5 \le x- \frac{1}{2} < 6 \qquad \text{or} \qquad
-5\le x - \frac{1}{2} < -4 \\
&\qquad\iff \frac{11}{2} \le x < \frac{13}{2} \qquad\text{or}\quad -\frac{9}{2} \le x \le -\frac{7}{2}. \end{align*}
Therefore $x \in \bigl[ \frac{11}{2}, \frac{13}{2} \bigr) \cup \bigl[-\frac{9}{2}, -\frac{7}{2}\bigr)$.

---

As an addendum, the validity of this answer is somewhat assured by a [GeoGebra plot](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/kfjhaptv):

[image]

The left-hand side of the equation is the function in blue, while the right-hand side is the function shown by a dotted red line.  Note that the horizontal line intersects the blue function along *two* intervals, hence we expect the set of solutions to consist of two disjoint intervals.  Moreover, the intervals shown in the graph appear to be precisely those found above.